# Drupal 7 Search Autocomplete

Tags: drupal, autocomplete

I am trying to setup Search Autocomplete module in Drupal 7 on my website (kooknet.be),
but it does not work. I use the ID selector below, but nothing happens

```
#search-block-form
```

However, when I look in the code with Firebug I see the following

```
<input id="edit-search-block-form--2" class="form-text search_autocomplete_processed ac_input" type="text" maxlength="128" size="15" value="" name="search_block_form" title="Geef de woorden op waarnaar u wilt zoeken." autocomplete="off">
```

Why is autocomplete="off"? Can this be the reason why it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your id should be #edit-search-block-form--2